# How to use a bowtie as a marking for an arrow in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, decorations

The title pretty much sums it up. The goal: the get a bowtie in the middle of a line segment like the one shown.
[image: this is the goal]

I have a minimum working example included with the output below. Currently the decoration is "Rays" but if I just replace with "\bowtie" I don't quite get what I'm after, and replacing with "$\bowtie$" gives even worse results. I also tried omitting the "\arrow{}" but that didn't help either. I'm sure there is some fundamental misunderstanding about the code in the preamble or how to decorations packages work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{latexsym, mathrsfs, color, tikz, multirow,bbm,mathtools, amsmath, amssymb, comment}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={  markings,  mark=at position #1 with
            {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\tikzset{-<-/.style={decoration={  markings,  mark=at position #1 with
            {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \draw[blue, thick, bend right=10][decoration={
        markings,
        mark={at position 1.2cm with {\arrow{Rays}}},
        },
        postaction={decorate}
        ](-1,.5)to(0,0)node[black]{$\bullet$};
    \draw[blue,thick](-.8,.5)node[above]{$\gamma$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htpb]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
    \draw[blue, thick, bend right=10][decoration={
        markings,
        mark={at position 1.2cm with {\arrow{\bowtie}}},
        },
        postaction={decorate}
        ](-1,.5)to(0,0)node[black]{$\bullet$};
    \draw[blue,thick](-.8,.5)node[above]{$\gamma$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: mytry]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome in the TeX.SE community.

Comment: @Sebastiano Long time lurker, first time poster. Thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `$\bowtie$` as a node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
\draw[blue, thick, bend right=10](-1,.5)to node[above,pos=.2]{$\gamma$}node[pos=1,sloped,rotate=90]{$\bowtie$}(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I was thinking more clearly when I posted this. It will take some minor adjusting to get it in the right spot. Thank you.